# Explore the possibility of autocorrelation for discrete factors

Tags: generalized-linear-model, autocorrelation, spatial

I have a dataset looks something like the following:

```
  status_group   date_recorded       gps_height  latitude   longitude     public_meeting
1   functional      3/14/2011            1390   -9.856322   34.93809      TRUE
2   functional      3/6/2013             1399   -2.147466   34.69877      NA
3   functional      2/25/2013            686    -3.821329   37.46066      TRUE
4   non functional  1/28/2013            263    -11.155298  38.48616      TRUE
5   functional      3/13/2011             0     -4.765587   39.17280      TRUE
6   functional      2/20/2011             62    -7.034139   39.20952      TRUE
```

I want to model `stats_group` in terms of other predictors and explore the possibility of spatial autocorrelation based on `latitude` and `longitude`.

In a continuous setting, we just simply fit our model using OLS and extract the residual, then we model the residual using kernel methods or Conditional Autoregressive model to explore spatial autocorrelation. However, in this case, since the response variable is discrete, the residuals extracted from a generalized model like logistics regression, seem to me, would not make sense.

Can anyone explain that how to deal with residuals in this case? Or better yet, how to determine autocorrelation if the residuals cannot be used?

Is there any suggestions about what packages to use in R to deal with this situation?